# Use Python Regex to search files and return filename

Tags: python, regex, file

Please help.
I'm searching several .txt files, in several directories for a pattern.  If there is a match, I would like to print the filename and location of the match.

Here is my code:

```
a = ('Z:/rodney/020year/2020-04/')
b = []
for y in os.listdir(a):
    b.append(a+y+'/')

for filename in b:
    path = filename
    for filenames in listdir(path):
        with open(path+filenames) as currentfile:
            text = currentfile.read()
            loan = re.compile(r'2 NNN                            \d LOANS')
        bb = loan.search(text)
        with open('z:/rodney/results.txt','a') as f:
            f.write(os.path.dirname(path)+' ')
            f.write(filenames[:-4]+'\n')
            f.write(bb)
```

Error message = "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None"

If there is a match, I would like to see only the filename and location of a match. I do not need to see "None" in every file where there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
bb = loan.search(text)
```

But if the string you are looking for is not found in `text`, `bb` will ne `None` and consequently `f.write(bb)` will raise an exception (you did not indicate which line of code was raising the exception, so this is an educated guess).

You need to modify your code to be:

```
bb = loan.search(text)
if bb:
    with open('z:/rodney/results.txt','a') as f:
        f.write(os.path.dirname(path)+' ')
        f.write(filenames[:-4]+'\n')
```

As an aside:

You have the statement `loan = re.compile(r'2 NNN                            \d LOANS')` in a loop. There is no need for that to be in a loop since it is invariant.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using string slicing and bunch of functions to parse file path by using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), where most of needed cases are already implemented. Also you can optimize your code by moving `re.compile()` out of loop (create once and use). Same with writing result - you don't need to reopen file every time, just open it once before loop start.

**Optimized code:**

```py
from pathlib import Path
import re

src_dir = Path(r"Z:\rodney\020year\2020-04")
res_fn = r"z:\rodney\results.txt"
with open(res_fn, "w+") as res_f:
    search_re = re.compile(r"2\sN{3}\s{28}\d\sLOANS")
    for directory in src_dir.iterdir():
        if directory.is_dir():
            for file in directory.iterdir():
                if file.is_file():
                    with open(file) as of:
                        bb = search_re.search(of.read())
                        if bb:
                            print(file.parent, file.stem, file=res_f)
                            print(bb.group(), file=res_f)
                            # res_f.write(file.parent + " " + file.stem + "\n" + bb.group())
```

Comment: Your code did execute- unfortunately the 'results.txt' file contained blank spaces... was it supposed to do this? or does this mean that the code found no matches??.

Comment: @belewis6i, cold you add small sample of data which should match your regex?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your source code, I optimized it.
I use `os.walk` to access each .txt file and then read it line by line in those txt files and save it in an enum. Then I will check each line in that enum with regex (I referenced **Olvin Roght-san**). If there is a match, it will print out the exact file location and line for you.

```
import os
import re

extension = [".txt"]
regex =  r"2\sN{3}\s{28}\d\sLOANS"
re_Search = re.compile(regex)
path = "Z:\rodney\020year\2020-04"
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        ext = os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower()       
        if ext in extension:
            with open(file_path, "r") as f:
                try:
                    f_content = f.readlines()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
            for l_idx, line in enumerate(f_content):
                if re_Search.search(line):
                    print(file_path)
                    print("At line: {l_idx}".format(l_idx = l_idx+1))
        else:
            print("Nothing!!")
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately after updating my code to reflect your changes, nothing happened.  It did not print a file or print "nothing!".  The code did not execute at all...?

Comment: Please check this pattern again to make sure it is correct or not? You can use Notepad ++ to do this.